# Using named converter in AdditionalCriteria statement

Tags: eclipselink, filtering, converters

Suppose there is an entity:
    `class Aaa {
      @Convert
      Bbb bbb
    }`
with properly defined named converter (via @Converter).
Now, create additional criteria like this:
    `@AdditionalCriteria("this.bbb IN :bbbList")`
and use like this:
    `entityManager.setProperty("bbbList", Arrays.asList(Bbb.X, Bbb.Y))`

And now the problem: synthetized IN clause looks like:
    `IN (Bbb.X.toString(), Bbb.Y.toString())`
In other words, named converter is not used, instead bbb is matched against the default string one. How can be this fixed?